# EXCEL, using an embedded object (.dot) as a report template

Tags: excel, ms-word, ole, vba

I have a Excel spreadsheet with a Word file embedded as an object.
When I open the object as a template and save it to a document file the name in the caption of Word is not changed 
and the object in Excel is affected.
Like this:

```
For Each OLE In ActiveSheet.OLEObjects
    If InStr(1, OLE.progID, "Word.Document", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
       OLE.Verb xlVerbPrimary
       Set WordDoc = OLE.Object
       WordDoc.SaveAs2 "c:\somewhere\a.doc", FileFormat:=WdSaveFormat.wdFormatDocument97
       Exit For
    End If
Next
```

I would expect that after "SaveAs" the title in Word changes to "a.doc" but the name is still "Document in somesheet.xls" 
and the embedded object in Excel is changed with further operations on WordDoc.

Is it possible to use the embedded Word file as a template without creating an intermediate file that has to be reopened?

Can I break the connection between the object and the open Word file?

EDIT: What I am after is creating a report using the object as a template. Now, SaveAs not only creates a file, but also affects the template.

Comment: It's not clear what you're after. If you use SaveAs you're going to create a file (a copy) in that location on a drive and you will need to open it in a separate instance of Word. The embedded object remains the same. What is supposed to happen to the copy? If you want to keep it in the Excel workbook, copy the OLE object, then manipulate that. (But you can't change the file name "Document in Workbook.xls".)

Comment: After the 'SaveAs' method, the document that is open in the Word instance is NOT the copy. The open document is connected and stays connected to the object in Excel. All changes to the document are also affecting the object (the template).
I want to break the connection between the document and the excel object.

Comment: As I said, if you want to work with a "copy" of the document stored as an OLE object you need to instantiate an instance of Word and open the file you saved in that instance. You cannot "break the connection" to the OLE object to make it independent.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a function to save the template and exit the document that is connected to Excel.
I think its a serious flaw in Excel that the connection cannot be broken from code.
I also didn't find a way to identify an object (when there are more .dot templates on a sheet). I'm using AltText for that purpose now.

```
Public Function SaveFileFromObject(EW As Excel.Worksheet _
        , sAltText As String, sFilename As String) As Boolean
    On Error GoTo EH
    Dim OLE As OLEObject, WD As Word.Document, bFound As Boolean
    bFound = False
    For Each OLE In EW.OLEObjects
        If InStr(1, OLE.progID, "Word.Document", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
           If OLE.ShapeRange.AlternativeText = sAltText Then
              OLE.Verb xlOpen
              Set WD = OLE.Object
              WD.SaveAs sFilename, FileFormat:=WdSaveFormat.wdFormatDocument97
              WD.Close False
              bFound = True
              Exit For
           End If
        End If
    Next
    SaveFileFromObject = bFound
EX: On Error Resume Next
    Set OLE = Nothing
    Set WD = Nothing
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Function
EH: MsgBox "Error in SaveFileFromObject: '" & err.Description & "'"
    SaveFileFromObject = False
    Resume EX
    Resume ' debug code
End Function
```